# How to pass arguments to ADF pipeline using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-data-factory

I have created a pipeline which has two parameters at pipeline level.
I want to send the values to these parameters using powershell and trigger the pipeline.
Any idea how to do it using Powershell.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Stack Overflow is not a free script writing service. Your own research and code attempts are expected. Edit the question to include your code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll leave a script that you can then modify to your needs:

```
Login-AzureRmAccount
Select-AzureRmSubscription -Subscription "yourSubId"

$dfname = "youDataFActoryName"
$rgName = "yourResourceGroupName"
$pipe = "pipeName"
$parameters = @{
    "param1" = "asdasd"
    "param2" = "123456"
}

Invoke-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Pipeline -DataFactoryName $dfname -ResourceGroupName $rgName -PipelineName $pipe -Parameter $parameters
```

Hope this helped!

Answer (score -1):

Parameter is to be passed as a `hashtable`. The `hashtable` is created using `@`

e.g :

```
$param = @{"year" = "2022"}

Invoke-AzDataFactoryV2Pipeline -ResourceGroupName "UAT" -DataFactoryName "ADF" -PipelineName "Snapshot" -Parameter $param
```