# How to trigger a Azure data factory pipeline with multiple parameter from postman

Tags: azure, rest, postman, azure-api-management, azure-data-factory

I have created a Azure Data Factory pipeline which have multiple pipeline parameter,which I need to enter all the time when pipeline trigger.Now I want to trigger this pipeline from  postman in my local system and i need to pass  parameters to pipeline from post.

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need to use postman? I've posted examples of doing this with Powershell and with Python.

Powershell: [How to pass arguments to ADF pipeline using powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53756570/how-to-pass-arguments-to-adf-pipeline-using-powershell)

Python: https://gist.github.com/Gorgoras/1fe534fd9b454412f81c8203c773c483

If your only option is to use the rest api, you can read about it and get some examples here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-rest-api

Hope this helped!!

Comment: Rest API makes it easier to integrate and becomes language agnostic. And Question clearly says he needs a REST API based solution

Comment: Well, thats why I linked the rest api quickstart at the end of my answer. BTW this is almost 3 years old

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger Azure Data Factory via a policy in API Management.

I've added a sample here: https://github.com/Azure/api-management-policy-snippets/blob/master/examples/Trigger%20Azure%20Data%20Factory%20Pipeline%20With%20Parameters.policy.xml

Answer (score 1):

Azure Docs doesn't provide examples on how to pass a parameter which I find weird also nowhere else on the internet have I found an example of how to pass multiple parameters via REST API, I guess most people use ADF shell to trigger it or python script.

Anyway, if someone else stumbles on the same question then here's the solution (which is quite simple).

Firstly, Create an Azure App Registration and generate client ID and client secret value.

Authenticate via REST API to get the Bearer Token

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/${TENANT_ID}/oauth2/token' \
--form 'grant_type="client_credentials"' \
--form 'client_id="${CLIENT_ID}"' \
--form 'client_secret="${CLIENT_SECRET_VALUE}"' \
--form 'resource="https://management.azure.com/"'
```

The response will contain a Bearer token, use it to trigger the pipeline. Replace subscription id, resource group name, and adf name.

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/${SUBSCRIPTION_ID}/resourceGroups/${RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME}/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/${ADF_NAME}/pipelines/trigger-pipeline-from-rest/createRun?api-version=2018-06-01' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer ${BEARER_TOKEN}' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "date":"2022-08-22",
    "param1":"param1 value",
    "param2":"some-value"
}'
```

Note: The app should have contributor access to ADF to trigger the pipeline.