# How to pass complex parameters to ADF via Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-data-factory

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53756570/how-to-pass-arguments-to-adf-pipeline-using-powershell) helped me get partway through what I need to do, but one of the parameters I need to pass to my Azure Data Factory pipeline is an array.

In the UI, I can just type it into the "default parameter" slot with ["x", "y", "z"] but I am not sure how to translate this syntactically to Powershell.

I also want to pass an object in, which in the ADF UI is of the format {"x":{"y":["z"],"a":"b","c":"d"}}.

How can I pass non-primitive parameters to my pipeline?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you please check my answer? If the answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if the other answer works or not, but I was able to get it working by using the -ParameterFile flag instead of the -Parameter flag, and passing in a path to a JSON file. This was a cleaner solution for me anyways as it allows git tracking of our parameter file rather than manually passing in parameters. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with ADF, but for translate a string to an object, I suggest you use json string and `ConvertFrom-Json`. Here is a sample:

```
$json = '{ "X":{ "Y":[ "1","2","3"]}, "a" : "b", "c":"d"}'
$obj = $json | ConvertFrom-Json
$obj.X
$obj.X.Y
$obj.a
$obj.c
```

And the output:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $obj.X

Y        
-        
{1, 2, 3}

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $obj.X.Y
1
2
3

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $obj.a
b
```

Hope it would be helpful to you.